# Given a tree, a start leaf and an end leaf, split it into up to 3 parts

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dom, graph, tree

I am doing some DOM manipulations with text-related elements (text node, p, span, b, i, etc.) where the problem can be formulated as follow:

Given a tree, a start leaf and an end leaf, split that tree into up to 3 parts:

- one part consists of everything to the left of start node
- one part consists of everything between start node and end node (inclusive)
- one part consists of everything to the right of end node

Note that left and right here refers to the pre-order traversal through the tree.

Nodes on the tree can be duplicated for the split as needed

So for example if I have the following tree:

[image]

where J is the start leaf and G is the end leaf, then after the split the result would be this:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I know it would probably require traversal from left to right using pre-order traversal/DFS, but I'm not sure on how to construct the new subtrees.

Comment: As stated, I could traverse the tree using DFS to figure out the nodes to the left and right of the start and end leafs, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: To the right of the end node? The right node is usually the last node, unless there is some kind of position on it.

Comment: @PHPglue I'm not sure what you mean, but if you see in the example H and D are "to the right" of G because if you do a pre-order traversal that's the order

Comment: Can you add some code providing your initial and desired data structures?

Comment: @MattWay I'm just looking for the general idea. In real life this is a DOM work so each node is a DOM node (including text node) and you have all the DOM traversal/manipulation methods at your disposal

Comment: What is the purpose of the data structure relevant to the DOM? Is the requirement to create the data structure in an HTML `document` or traverse the existing data structure within an HTML `document`? What do "left" and "right" refer to, indexes within a `NodeList`?

Comment: I am working with the DOM, so just like the question I have an element somewhere in the DOM to serve as the root of a tree, then two nodes to serve as the start and end nodes, and I need to split that DOM tree as required in the question. Left and right just refer to the pre-order traversal order, if node J is encountered after I then J is right of I

Comment: @Chin While you are looking for the general idea, it is still good practice to provide some sort of example for people to work with. This avoids any assumptions on their part, and provides a common framework for people answering to tackle the problem. You are also much more likely to get useful answers. It also gives you the opportunity to show what you have tried.

Comment: So what is left/right when you want to go from I to G?

Answer (score 0):

Create a preorder index. It's a lookup table from a `Node` to its position in the preorder traversal.

Write a `cloneWithFilter` function that takes a node and a predicate and returns the cloned node or `null`. The idea is that a node should be included if it passes the filter or if any of its children pass the filter. The pseudocode looks like this:

```
Node? cloneWithFilter(Node node, Predicate<Node> filter) {
    val newNode = new Node(node.value);
    newNode.children = node.children.map(c -> cloneWithFilter(c, filter))
                                    .filter(c -> c != null);
    return filter(node) || !newNode.children.empty() : newNode : null;
}
```

You can use this to create the parts, just use different filters.
For example, for the middle part you could write:

`cloneWithFilter(root, node -> preOrderIndex[node] >= preOrderIndex[from] && 
                              preOrderIndex[node] <= preOrderIndex[to]
 )`